What is the difference between E and E′?


From Roger Muncaster's book A Level Physics page 566 in the 4th edition. I'm coming from Tom Duncan's Advanced Physics where the only driver cell/ accumulator was E. What's the diff between E and E'?
Here the experiment is comparing resistances.(Muncaster)
The part shown measures Internal resistance of a cell by first testing on open circuit and external circuit (Tom Duncan)
edited to include both. "It is usually an accumulator" but the one he (T.D) shows is in position of E. I have a problem with how current is supposed to flow when the two cells are connected.(And the purpose each current serves in measuring resistances using the potentiometer) I thought the accumulator is only one (E that maintains a steady current and p.d across the potentiometer wire)

Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Those are just two different electromotive forces. The exact differences in the ways of the mechanics of those sources might be a question better suited for Electrical Engineering SE.

I don't have Tom Duncan's book, but my guess is that he is describing a Wheatstone bridge. Muncaster describes this on page 557 (of the 4th edition) where he calls it a metre bridge. The circuit you you show (page 566) is a potentiometer not a bridge and Muncaster describes in the text below the diagram how it works.

@naturallyInconsistent the text says nothing about how the two cells work

In this circuit you have two cells (i.e., batteries): the "Driver cell" and the "Accumulator". There's no reason to expect the two to have the same EMF, hence the book labels one of them as \$E\$ and the other as \$E'\$.
There's nothing stopping you from having a circuit where \$E = E'\$, of course, which sounds like the result in Duncan's book.

edited to include both. "It is usually an accumulator" but the one he shows is in position of E. I have a problem with how current is supposed to flow when the two cells are connected.(And the purpose each current serves) I thought the accumulator is only one (E that maintains a steady current and p.d across the wire)

@BeardlessDev I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid. You got two E's, and they can be equal. (You'll need to know how to treat the case where they're not equal, as well.)
